# populate bash script from web app

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, web-applications, salt-stack

I want to create a web app (like a form) where users can pass values when creating a server. It should be such as:

instance tag

prod/non-prod

type of server (web, files, db, etc)

and then i want to pass these values to a script on my cloud-init folder so that the server generates grains in salt and uses pillars to populate configuration files appropriately.

Since i am mostly using Python and Salt (python based), i was going to use django, flask, angular.js... but i dont know how to use them .. or if it is even possible to do this.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have three fully supported choices:

1. [Import the Salt Client API directly](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients/index.html#client-apis)
2. [Invoke the Salt Reactor event API](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/reactor/index.html)
3. [Run the Salt API REST interface](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/netapi/index.html)

In my opinion, the sooner you learn and leverage the Salt Reactor event system, the more doors will open for you.